# Histogram3D using sums instead of counts

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

I'm trying to create a 3d histogram/ matrix plot pair. My data is in the form

```
{{TTR1,TBF1},{TTR2,TBF2},....}
```

What I would like is to modify the Histogram3D so instead of having the counts of each bin  on the z axis I would have the sum of TTR in that bin. I would also like the modify the matrix plot in the same way.

I've hacked an example in the help to get this far;

```
hist := Histogram3D[Log[10, dateFilter[[All, 2]]], {-4, 4, 0.25}, 
Function[{xbins, ybins, counts}, Sow[counts]], 
AxesLabel -> {Style["TTR (log(hours))", 16], 
Style["TBF (log(hours))", 16]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Dryer 1 TBF and TTR Counts", 18], 
ChartStyle -> RGBColor[27/255, 121/255, 169/255], 
ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2}];
{g, {binCounts}} = Reap[hist];
mPlot := MatrixPlot[First@binCounts, ImageSize -> Large]
Row[{g, mPlot}]
```

In this case my data list is

```
dateFilter[[All, 2]]={{TTR1,TBF1},{TTR2,TBF2}....}
```

I would also like to fix this axis on the MatrixPlot so it has the same range labels as the histogram.

Also is there a better way to do the log axes on the Histogram? I've just taken the Log of the data but it would be better if I could just modify the axes to show 1,10,100,....

[image]

**Edit**

I've re-plotted by data using kgulers code. The function I used was

```
Histogram3D[Log[10, dateFilter[[All, 2]]], {-4, 4, 0.25}, 
heightF[dateFilter[[All, 2]]][Total, First], styles, 
AxesLabel -> {Style["TTR (log(hours))", 16], 
Style["TBF (log(hours))", 16], Style["Sum TTR (hours)", 16]}, 
ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 2}]
```

[image]

It looks like my data has stratified into 3 groups of TTR (which may be what is really going on). I was kind of expecting the same plot with different z values but if that's what's going on then that's what's going on.

Thanks kguler and belisarius. Give me a day to check that this is all ok and I'll tick this one off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A custom height function for `Histogram3D`:

Key ideas: (1) get the list of data points in each bin using `BinLists`, (2) Map `func2` to each 2D data point and `func1` to the results to define the heights for each bin:

```
ClearAll[binListF, heightF];
binListF[data_][bins_, counts_] := BinLists[data, {bins[[1]]}, {bins[[2]]}];
heightF[data_][func1_: Total, func2_: First, binning_: Automatic] := 
 Map[func1, Map[func2, 
   HistogramList[data, binning, binListF[data]][[2]] /. {} -> {0, 0}, {-2}], {-2}] &
```

**Data and styles:**

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100, 2}];
styles = Sequence @@ {BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300,  ChartStyle -> Opacity[.6], 
   ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleCube", 
    "Segments" -> 12, "ColorScheme" -> 46]};
```

**Usage examples:**

```
Histogram3D[data, Automatic, heightF[data][Total, First], styles] (* OP's example *)
```

[image]

**Bin specifications:**

```
Row[Column[{Style[Row[{"binning: ", #}], 18, "Panel"],
Histogram3D[data, #, heightF[data][Total, First, #], styles]}, Center] & /@
   {{{-2, 2, 0.5}, {-3, 3,1.5}}, "Knuth", "Sturges", "FreedmanDiaconis", "Scott", "Wand"}]
```

[image]

**Aggregation functions:**

```
Row[Column[{Style[Row[{"heightF[data][", #[[1]], ", ", #[[2]], "]"}], 18, "Panel"],
  Histogram3D[data, Automatic, heightF[data][#[[1]], #[[2]]], styles]}, Center] & /@
  {{Total, Last}, {Total, Mean}, {Max, Mean}, {Min, Mean}, {Max, Min}, {Min, Max}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the Histogram, you could do something like:

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {200, 2}];
Histogram3D[data, {.5}, 
 Function[{xbs, ybs, c}, 
  Table[Total[ Select[data, x[[1]] <= #[[1]] < x[[2]] && y[[1]] <= #[[2]] < y[[2]] &][[All, 1]]], 
        {x, xbs}, {y, ybs}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]