# Calculate mean of values in bins

Tags: data, histograms

**Problem description**:
I have a list of $\{x,y\}$ pairs. I'd like to divide $x$ into equal[*] bins, say $bx_1, bx_2, \ldots$, calculate $\left<y\right>$ for every bin and then plot the bin values versus the means. I.e., plot $bx_i$ versus $\left<y\right>_i$ with `ListPlot[]`.

**Question**: I've already done it manually, but I was wondering whether:

1. exists a builtin function in *Mathematica* that does what I want.
2. exists a builtin function that I could use in my own implementation (e.g., `HistogramList[]`?).

[*] Bins with the same interval. Equally spaced intervals.

---

**EDIT**: Largely off-topic, but in `R` it turns out to be very easy with the `fields` package:

```
library('fields')
df <- read.table('my.dat')    # V1 -> off-axis distance, V2 -> energy
st <- stats.bin(x=df$V1, y=df$V2, N=100)
df2 <- as.data.frame(st$stats["mean",])

# Plot mean energy for every distance bin
# EDIT: Actually I should plot against `centers` of `st`, but anyway.
names(df2) <- c('mean.energy')
plot(df2$mean.energy, type="s",
    xlab="Off-axis distance (mm)", ylab="Mean Energy (MeV)")
```

[image]

Comment: Define "equal" - interval span, number of elements, what?

Comment: Take a look at `BinLists` and `BinCount`.

Comment: possibly related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3996/1089

Comment: see also: [Histogram3D using sums instead of counts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20132/125)

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17734

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw this out, used it for a similar problem, since I didn't recall and simple built-in to do this:

```
(* test data *)
test = RandomInteger[20, {100, 2}];

(* number of bins *)
numbins = 10;

(* setup *)
{t1, t2} = Transpose@test;
{bins, bincnt} = ConstantArray[0, {2, numbins}];

{min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}[t1]];

intervals = 
  Interval/@Partition[Table[x, {x, min, max, Subtract[max, min]/numbins}], 2, 1];

binpos = (Pick[Range@numbins, IntervalMemberQ[intervals, #]] & /@ t1)[[All, 1]];

Inner[(bincnt[[#]]++; bins[[#]] += #2) &, binpos, t2];


(* results *)
Transpose[{List @@@ intervals, bins, bincnt}]
mean = bins/bincnt

(*

{{{{0, 2}}, 149, 13}, {{{2, 4}}, 133, 11}, {{{4, 6}}, 101, 9}, {{{6, 8}}, 44, 8}, 
 {{{8, 10}}, 87, 12}, {{{10, 12}}, 116, 10}, {{{12, 14}}, 127, 12}, 
 {{{14, 16}}, 80, 8} {{{16, 18}}, 83, 8}, {{{18, 20}}, 86, 9}}

{149/13, 133/11, 101/9, 11/2, 29/4, 58/5, 127/12, 10, 83/8, 86/9}

*)
```

Example result shows a list of lists, each with the interval, total, and count, and the mean of the bins.

Comment: @Kuba: ? do you mean if a value (e.g. 2) falls on two intervals (e.g. [1,2] and [2,3])? Taken care of by selection of first interval.

Comment: I've made a mistake, I'm sorry :)

Comment: @Kuba: No worries, I'd forgotten about this post - curious why it came alive ;-)

Comment: OP made an edit :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option, using `GatherBy`, `Floor` and `Rules`.

```
binListsBy[data_List,binSize_,binIndex_Integer,aggrateFunctions_,nullValue_:Null]:=Module[{max,min},
    {min,max}=Floor[Through@{Min,Max}@data[[All,binIndex]],binSize];
    binListsBy[data,{min,max,binSize},binIndex,aggrateFunctions,nullValue]
]

binListsBy[data_List,{min_,max_,binSize_},binIndex_Integer,aggrateFunctions_,nullValue_:Null]:=
  Module[{intervals,findInterval,binRule},

    intervals=Partition[Range[min,max+binSize,binSize],2,1];
    findInterval={Floor[#,binSize],Floor[#,binSize]+binSize}&;
    binRule=findInterval@#[[1,binIndex]] -> {findInterval@#[[1,binIndex]],aggrateFunctions@@Transpose@#}&/@GatherBy[data,findInterval[#[[binIndex]]]&];

    binRule=Dispatch@Join[binRule,{{a_,b_}:> {{a,b},nullValue}}];
    intervals/.binRule
]

test = RandomInteger[{20,100}, {100, 2}];
binedList=binListsBy[test,20,1,N@Mean[#2]/Length[#1]&,0]
```

> {{{20,40},5.36111},{{40,60},3.18519},{{60,80},4.10938},{{80,100},6.91837},{{100,120},59.}}

Using ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@{binedList[[All,1,2]],binedList[[All,-1]]}
        ,Joined->True
        ,InterpolationOrder->0
        ,Frame->True
        ,FrameLabel->{{"Mean Energy (MeV)"},{"Off-axis distance (mm)"}}
        ,PlotStyle->{Thick,Darker@Green}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is another version which uses `BinList[]` as per @rasher's suggestion:

```
binAndMean[xdata_List, ydata_List, nbins_Integer] :=
 Module[{xbins, bins},
  xbins = Array[# &, nbins + 1, {Min@xdata, Max@xdata}];
  bins = BinLists[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], {xbins}, {{-Infinity, +Infinity}}];
  Table[Last /@ Flatten[bins[[k]], 1] // Mean, {k, 1, Length@bins}]]
```

I could have made the function accept a list of {x,y} pairs, but I found this more convenient  because I already have my data as separate lists.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are extracting your tuples from a dataset, then you can do:

```
Mean /@ Table[Cases[Normal@myDataset[All, {#valueToBin, #valueOfBin} &], {x_ /; Round@(x/bin) == i, y_} -> {Round@(x/bin)*bin, y}, Infinity], {i, min/bin, max/bin}]
```

This may seem complicated, so lets break it down:

- `min` and `max` are the smallest / largest values in `valuesToBin`
- `bin` is the size of your bin.
- `Normal@myDataset[All, {#valueToBin, #valueOfBin} &]` retrieves your list of tuples

Since we want the mean of all the values within our bin, it would be nice if we had a nested list, such that each sublist contained all the tuples of our bin.

That is where `Cases` comes in. Let `tuples=Normal@myDataset[All, {#valueToBin, #valueOfBin} &]`, then

`Cases[tuples, {x_ /; Round@(x/bin) == i, y_} -> {Round@(x/bin)*bin, y}, Infinity]`

Uses the pattern `{x_ /; Round@(x/bin) == i, y_}` to find all tuples which have an `x` when divided by the bin (and rounded) fit the integer value, `i`, of that bin. The association `{x_ /; Round@(x/bin) == i, y_} -> {Round@(x/bin)*bin, y}` has `Cases` return those tuples replacing the first value with that of the bin; `Infinity` searches to match at any level.

We then `Table` this `Cases` over all possible `i` values (found between `min` and `max`). And mean then gives you the answer.

For example:

```
tuples = RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {1000, 2}];
min = Min@tuples[[;; , 1]];
max = Max@tuples[[;; , 1]];
bin = 10;

Mean /@ Table[
  Cases[tuples, {x_Integer /; Round@(x/bin) == i, 
     y_} -> {Round@(x/bin)*bin, y}, Infinity], {i, min/bin, max/bin}]
```

and done

```
{{10, 936/17}, {20, 7335/134}, {30, 5416/109}, {40, 6609/116}, {50, 
  5621/96}, {60, 6148/117}, {70, 5045/99}, {80, 6531/118}, {90, 2602/
  45}, {100, 1989/35}}
```