# 3D binning keeping the values

Tags: list-manipulation, data, algorithm

I have `N` points in the from of triplets `{xi,yi,zi}`.

I would like to bin them on a grid `nbin^2` based on their `x`, `y` values. Now, the key difference compared to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44775/calculate-mean-of-values-in-bins?rq=1) is that I would like to compute average values in each bin for binned number of points and obtain `{xav,yav,zav}` for bin 1, up to `nbin^2` and to plot `nbin^2` number of points instead of initial `N` points.

I do not want to plot it against bin values as in example above, and please note that `x`, `y` will not be *equidistant*.
I started the code for pair {xi,yi} and it does what I want (please see below), I am stuck how to effectively extend it in 3D and ideally optimise in line with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178714/mathematica-fast-2d-binning-algorithm).

```
test = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {1000, 2}];

xmin = Min@test[[1 ;;]][[All, 1]];
xmax = Max@test[[1 ;;]][[All, 1]];
ymin = Min@test[[1 ;;]][[All, 2]];
ymax = Max@test[[1 ;;]][[All, 2]];
nbin = 15.;

t2 = BinLists[
 test[[1 ;; ;; 1]], {xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/nbin}, {ymin, 
ymax, (ymax - ymin)/nbin}];
Length /@ {t2, t2[[1]]}

(* getting rid of empty bins*)

  ct2 = Replace[t2, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}];   

  ave1 = Map[Mean, ct2[[#]], 1] & /@ Range[Length[ct2]];
  ListPlot /@ {test, ave1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 2;
nbins = 15;
testb = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {1000, n}];
epsilon = 1*^-10;
indexes = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) nbins Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[testb][[{1, 2}]]]];
```

Make the data entries strings, and modify the `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` suboption value to make the list of repeated entries a string:

```
values = ToString /@ testb;

System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" ->{"TreatRepeatedEntries" ->
  (ToString @ {##} &)}];
binmeansZ = SparseArray[indexes -> values];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];
```

Process the sparse  array to change strings to expressions and take the means:

```
newlist = Replace[binmeansZ["NonzeroValues"] /. x_String :> ToExpression[x], 
   y : {ConstantArray[_, Dimensions[testb][[2]]] ..} :> Mean[y], 1];
```

Display:

```
ListPlot[{testb, newlist}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Small], Blue], Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 GridLines -> {Range[-100, 100, 200/15], Range[-100, 100, 200/15]}]
```

[image]

For `n = 3` we get

```
c = {Red, Blue};
ListPointPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], First[c = RotateLeft[c]]]] & /@ 
  {testb, newlist} // Row
```

[image]

Comment: kglr thank you so much ! It is on the right track ! Just not sure what if I use something like XY=Table[ {40000*n/256., 10000*m/256.}, {n, 1, 256}, {m, 1, 256}] ; testb=Flatten[XY,1]; for nbins=15, I get 60 instead of expected 225 binned values ?

Comment: @BBmath, the `indexes` was wrong, now fixed.

Comment: 2D works great, but if you put something like dataXYZ = 
  Table[ {40000*n/256., 10000*m/256., 20000*l/256.}, {n, 1, 256}, {m, 
    1, 256}, {l, 1, 256}]; ; testb=Flatten[dataXYZ,2]; I get nbin^3 rather than nbins^2 points in newlist.Thanks again !

Comment: @BBmath, now I see `nbins^2` is for both 2D and 3D. I will post an update  with a fix.

Comment: @kgrl, it seems like that the fix is 'indexes = 
  1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) nbins Transpose[
      Rescale /@ Transpose[testb[[All, {1, 2}]]]]];' Thank you !

Comment: @BBmath, yess!! Glad it worked.  Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: @BBmath, added the fix. Now it should produce `nbin^2` grid for both 2D and 3D input.