# How to generate a histogram distribution with height function

Tags: distributions

According to the Mathematica documentation the `HistogramList` command allows to specify a height function `fh`, as third argument, that allows to compute the height based on the bin location and the bin count.

```
HistogramList[data,bspec,fh]
```

The command `HistogramDistribution` seems to be related but, according to the documentation, has only the binning options of `HistogramList`.

Is it possible to influence the height of the bins of a `HistogramDistribution` or to generate such a distribution from a `HistogramList`?

Another option would be to change the `HistogramDistribution` after creating it. The meaning of the elements of this structure seems quite obvious, but I lack knowledge how to change the structure. Trying to change it in the obvious way, `histdist[[2]] = {{...}}` seems to break it.

Comment: Do you really mean `HistoryList` and `HistoryDistribution`?

Comment: Does the example in [HistogramList >>Scope >> Height Specifications](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html) help?

Comment: @bill  `HistogramList` and `HistogramDistribution`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** You can replace the vector of `PDFValues` (i.e., Part (2,1)) of the `DataDistribution` object returned by `HistogramDistribution` with a vector that has the same length and sum.

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
D1 = HistogramDistribution[data1];
D2 = D1;
D2[[2, 1]] =  N@Total[D1["PDFValues"]] 
            Normalize[RandomInteger[10, {Length@D1["PDFValues"]}], Total];

D1["PDFValues"]
```

> {0.02, 0.18, 0.38, 0.24, 0.14, 0.02, 0.02}

```
D2["PDFValues"]
```

> {0.236842, 0.105263, 0.184211, 0.263158, 0.157895, 0.0526316, 0.}

```
Row[DiscretePlot[PDF[#, x], {x, -4, 4, .01}, ImageSize -> 300]& /@ {D1, D2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Through[{Mean, Median, Variance,  Moment[#, 2] &}@#] & /@ {D1, D2}
```

> {{-0.06, -0.210526, 1.44973, 1.45333},
>        {-0.342105, -0.142857, 2.47946, 2.59649}}

Replace `Normalize[RandomInteger[10, {Length@D1["PDFValues"]}], Total]` with your choice of a vector that has appropriate length and sum.

**Previous version:**

From [Histogram >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And from [HistogramList >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And mimicking the example in [HistogramList >> Scope >> Height Specifications](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html)

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];

accumulatedCount[bins_, counts_] := Accumulate[counts]
Row@{Histogram[data, {1}, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Histogram[data, {1}, accumulatedCount, ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we can construct custom height functions like:

```
foo1[bins_, counts_] := bins[[All, 1]]^2;
foo2[bins_, counts_] := Range[Length@counts];

Row@{Histogram[data, {1}, ImageSize -> 300],
  Histogram[data, {1}, foo1, ImageSize -> 300],
  Histogram[data, {1}, foo2, ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only requirement is that the height function returns a list of length that is equal to the number of bins:

**See also:** [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20154/125) to a related question for an example of how to construct a custom 3D height function for `Histogram3D`.

Comment: Thanks, this tells me how to use the height function of `HistogramList` but I need a `HistogramDistribution`, not only to plot a histogram but also for statistical operations (strictly speaking I do not need it normalized).